# Display error on create alertDialog()

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am a beginner android developer. 
I have a database table that counts the following columns: _id, fistName, lastName and username what is set to unique.

When I add another person in my table and the username already exist I create an AlertDialog, but this AlertDialog does not appear.

This is my source code:

```
try {
        personRepository.AddPerson(persons);
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException ex) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("User already exist!");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Choose another username!")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: post your AddPerson code.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
AlertDialog alert;
alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("Message")
                .setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
```

Comment: what is the problem you found with OP and suggested this code? Could you please explain in your answer?

Comment: Sometimes Context , getContext() or even getApplicationContext() results in this exception. Try passing

`this`
or

`YourActivity.this`
Activity inherits from Context so it works, although i really don't know why getting the context as it should be done it won't work, giving that weird exception.

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` passing the entire applications context, and `YourActivity.this` passes the avtivity context. I think, that is the major difference between these two.

Answer (score 0):

If your `AddPerson` method call `insertOrThrow` then change

```
catch (SQLiteConstraintException ex)
```

to

```
catch (SQLException ex)
```